# react-native-track-player: How can i fix TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'TrackPlayer.STATE_NONE') in android?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-track-player

> I am trying to implement react - native - track - player, but i am stuck with above error
> please guide me how can i resolve this error.and i have already reinstalled the app
> two times but in my
> case error is not short out.i am sharing piece of code below
> for reference.
>
> 1. I have made a service.js file like this

```
    import TrackPlayer from 'react-native-track-player';
    module.exports = async function () {
    TrackPlayer.addEventListener("remote-play", () => TrackPlayer.play())
    TrackPlayer.addEventListener("remote-pause", () => TrackPlayer.pause())}
```

> 2. import it in index.js like this

```
    import {AppRegistry}from 'react-native';
    import TrackPlayer from "react-native-track-player"
    import {App}from './App  
    AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
    TrackPlayer.registerPlaybackService(() => require("./service"))
```

> 3. finally this is my setup file code please go through it.

```
     componentDidMount() {
            TrackPlayer.updateOptions({
                    stopWithApp: true
                    , capabilities: [TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PLAY, TrackPlayer
                            .CAPABILITY_PAUSE
                    ]
                    , compactCapabilities: [
                            TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PLAY
                            , TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_PAUSE,
                            // TrackPlayer.CAPABILITY_SEEK_TO
                    ]
            , });
            this.setUpTrackPlayer()
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
    TrackPlayer.destroy();
     }
    setUpTrackPlayer = async () => {
    try {
            await TrackPlayer.setupPlayer();
            await TrackPlayer.add({
                    id: '1'
                    , url: 'n/w url'
                    , title: 'Example'
                    , artist: 'ajay'
            , });
            console.log('Tracks added');
    }
      and  for play and pause i am using 
     TrackPlayer.play() & TrackPlayer.pause()
```